# how to adjust vertical line distance in tabular form using math mode

Tags: tables, math-mode

in my code, the vertical distance is too low and formulas seem to converge. How I can avoid this?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişen ülkeler için iş döngüleri istatistikleri}     
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\label{tab:buscycle1}
\textbf{İstatistik} & \textbf{Türkiye}   & \textbf{Brezilye} & \textbf{Güney Kore} &\textbf{ Güney Afrika }& \textbf{Arjantin} & \textbf{Meksika} & \textbf{Gelişen ülke ortalama}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
 $\sigma_{y}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{c}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{i}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{m}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{tb}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
 c  & & & & & & & \\
 $\dfrac{g}{y}$  & & & & & & & \\
 i  & & & & & & & \\
 x  & & & & & & & \\
 m  & & & & & & & \\
 tb  & & & & & & & \\
 cay  & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
 y & & & & & & & \\
 c & & & & & & & \\
 g & & & & & & & \\
 i & & & & & & & \\
 x & & & & & & & \\
 m & & & & & & & \\
 tby & & & & & & & \\
 cay & & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: I'd recommend to not use `adjustbox` to make the table fit into the textwidth as it will lead to inconsistent and sometimes illegibly small font sizes. Instead instroduce linebreaks in the column headers. You might also want to take a look at the `booktabs` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! So I have done the following: First, the spacing between the `\dfrac{}{}` has been increased by changing `\\` to `\\[2em]`. Second, you can stretch all the table rows via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}`. The `1` is the default value, increase to see the result.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % <===== STARTS HERE
    \begin{table}[h]
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
    \caption{Seçilmiş gelişen ülkeler için iş döngüleri istatistikleri}     
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
        \label{tab:buscycle1}
        \textbf{İstatistik} & \textbf{Türkiye}   & \textbf{Brezilye} & 
        \textbf{Güney Kore} & \textbf{ Güney Afrika } & 
        \textbf{Arjantin} & \textbf{Meksika} & \textbf{Gelişen ülke ortalama}  \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
         $\sigma_{y}$ & & & & & & & \\[1.5em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{c}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{i}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{m}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]
         $\dfrac{\sigma_{tb}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\[2em]\hline
         \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
         c  & & & & & & & \\
         $\dfrac{g}{y}$  & & & & & & & \\
         i  & & & & & & & \\
         x  & & & & & & & \\
         m  & & & & & & & \\
         tb  & & & & & & & \\
         cay  & & & & & & & \\[2em]\hline
          \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
         y & & & & & & & \\
         c & & & & & & & \\
         g & & & & & & & \\
         i & & & & & & & \\
         x & & & & & & & \\
         m & & & & & & & \\
         tby & & & & & & & \\
         cay & & & & & & & \\[2em]\hline
         \hline
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table} 
}                   % <===== ENDS HERE
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion that uses `booktabs` for the horizontal lines with some additional spacing around them and the `\addlinespace` command for additional space around the rows containing fractions. With the `makecell` package you can easily insert linebreaks in column headers. With the `tabular*` environment and `\extracolsep{\fill}}` I made sure that the table fits into the textwidth even without the use of `adustwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişen ülkeler için iş döngüleri istatistikleri}
\label{tab:buscycle1}     
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llllllll}
\toprule
\thead{İstatistik} & \thead{Türkiye}   & \thead{Brezilye} & \thead{Güney\\ Kore} &\thead{Güney\\ Afrika }& \thead{Arjantin} & \thead{Meksika} & \thead{Gelişen ülke\\ ortalama}  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
 $\sigma_{y}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{c}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{i}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{m}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{\sigma_{tb}}{\sigma_{y}}$ & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
 c  & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 $\dfrac{g}{y}$  & & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
 i  & & & & & & & \\ 
 x  & & & & & & & \\
 m  & & & & & & & \\
 tb  & & & & & & & \\
 cay  & & & & & & & \\
 \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
 y & & & & & & & \\
 c & & & & & & & \\
 g & & & & & & & \\
 i & & & & & & & \\
 x & & & & & & & \\
 m & & & & & & & \\
 tby & & & & & & & \\
 cay & & & & & & & \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add vertical space above and below each cells' content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}   % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]       % <---
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\caption{Seçilmiş gelişen ülkeler için iş döngüleri istatistikleri}
\label{tab:buscycle1}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}                                          % <---
    \makegapedcells                                             % <---
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{l}}     
    \hline
\thead{İstatistik} & \thead{Türkiye}   & \thead{Brezilye} & \thead{Güney\\ Kore} &\thead{Güney\\ Afrika }& \thead{Arjantin} & \thead{Meksika} & \thead{Gelişen ülke\\ ortalama}  \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Varyans}} \\
$\sigma_{y}$                        & & & & & & & \\    
$\dfrac{\sigma_{c}}{\sigma_{y}}$    & & & & & & & \\
$\dfrac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{y}}$    & & & & & & & \\
$\dfrac{\sigma_{i}}{\sigma_{y}}$    & & & & & & & \\
$\dfrac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$    & & & & & & & \\
$\dfrac{\sigma_{m}}{\sigma_{y}}$    & & & & & & & \\
$\dfrac{\sigma_{tb}}{\sigma_{y}}$   & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
 \multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Y ile korelasyon}} \\
 c      & & & & & & & \\    
$\dfrac{g}{y}$  & & & & & & & \\    
i      & & & & & & & \\
x      & & & & & & & \\
m      & & & & & & & \\
tb     & & & & & & & \\
cay    & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\textbf{Otokorelasyon}} \\
y       & & & & & & & \\
c       & & & & & & & \\
g       & & & & & & & \\
i       & & & & & & & \\
x       & & & & & & & \\
m       & & & & & & & \\
tby     & & & & & & & \\
cay     & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]